# Make PHP object behave as string so that is_string returns true

Tags: php

Plain question:
Is there a way to make a PHP object $myObject return true when put into the is_string-function?

```
$myObject = new FancyStringMockClass();
var_dump(is_string($myObject));
//bool(true)
```

So far, my research says  it is not possible, but maybe I'm wrong.

Context: I'm implementing a kind of adapter between a CraftCMS site and our ElasticSearch index, or you could say extending the Craft-Elasticsearch plugin. I'm trying to make the results transparent for the frontend using the search results, so that the code searching for content can either be an ES or DB query, but the frontend remains agnostic (hope I used the term correctly).
When it comes to dependent asset objects, it is quite hard to mimick them and so I'm trying to find a workaround for the case my objects are passed to the imager-x plugin which seems to also accept url-strings instead of Asset-Objects. So if my object was tested for is_string positively (is_string is the code imager-x uses) it would just need to output the image url in __toString() and imager-x would be fine with it, not expecting a full Asset object.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: you can [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) which can work with Objects - [perhaps as you hope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Comment: According to PHP documentation, that's not possible.